# How to add / modify existing jquery functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable/enable a button based on the checkbox, which I am unable to do. Here is the sample I worked on. For enabled and disabled, different buttons have to be used.

```
function toggleContinue() {
  $(document).ready(function() {    
        $("#swpRequired").click(function() {
              $("input,select").change(function() {
                $("#disableContinue").attr("style", "display:inline-block");
                $("#continueButton").attr("style", "display:none");
              });
         });

         $("#swpRequired").click(function() {
              $("input,select").change(function() {
                 $("#disableContinue").attr("style", "display:none");
                 $("#continueButton").attr("style", "display:inline-block;");
               });
          });
    });
 }
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI (which may replace the buttons with a bunch of UI junk) or just raw HTML with jQuery?  If it's raw HTML with jQuery, you should be able to set the `disabled` property to disable the button with very little fuss. `$("#myButton").attr("disabled", true);`

Comment: I have to use different buttons, so I think it may not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this. use prop method of jquery

```js
function s()
{
if($("#a").prop('disabled')==false)
$("#a").prop('disabled','true')
else
$("#a").removeAttr('disabled')

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"  onchange="s()" id="b"/>enable
<input type="button" value="click" id="a">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `attr()` to disable/enable the button based on checkbox's value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#swpRequired").click(function() {
      $("#continueButton").attr("disabled", this.checked);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="swpRequired" />
<button id="continueButton">continue</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change event` and take the help of `disabled` property of `button`.

Solution will be like:

```js
$(document).on('change', "#checkbox", function()
{
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true)
  {
    $("#btn").prop('disabled',true)
  }
  else
  {
    $("#btn").prop('disabled',false)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>enable
<input type="button" value="click" id="btn">
```

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'